# Nav bar links do not have shadow on roll over

Tags: html, css

On rollover of navbar links, I can make them change colour but it does not have a shadow at the bottom.

How do I make it have a shadow at the bottom like before rollover?

http://peter-russell.github.io/nav-shadow/

Comment: I'm not sure is this what you want, because your question not really clear. but I saw your site and I think you need `overflow: hidden` for `#nav`

Comment: Or just remove the height from the #nav element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough but if you don't need to cover the navigation bar's shadow when hovering the buttons, just shrink your top and bottom padding regarding the button itself like the following:

```
#nav a {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Hope this is what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
   #nav li a:hover {
        background-color: darkgrey;
        box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
    }
```